# Dar de alta registro MVC

Tags: c#, razor, mvc

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto MVC

```
public class EmpleadoController : Controller
{
    private readonly SdEmpleado _empleadoRepository = new SdEmpleado();
    // GET: Empleado
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }


    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Empleado entity) // Si hace POST recibe el modelo empleado
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Guardamos
            _empleadoRepository.InsertOrUpdate(entity);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(); //En caso no lo sea regresa a la Vista y muestra errores
    }
}
```

Al dar de alta un registro me da el sigueite error

```
    Error de compilación
Descripción: Error durante la compilación de un recurso requerido para dar servicio a esta solicitud. Revise los detalles de error específicos siguientes y modifique el código fuente en consecuencia.

Mensaje de error del compilador: CS0103: The name 'model' does not exist in the current context

Error de código fuente:


Línea 1:  @using System.Web.Mvc.Html
Línea 2:  @model Prueba.EntidadesDominio.Empleado
Línea 3:  
Línea 4:  @{


Archivo de origen: D:\PruebasC#\Mantenimiento\Prueba.Web\Views\Empleado\Create.cshtml    Línea: 2
```

Vista

```
 @using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@model Prueba.EntidadesDominio.Empleado

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Create</title>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

Comment: de casualida cambiaste de version de framework en el proyecto web?

Comment: Por qué la vista tiene un Doc HTML?

Comment: Hola Leandro, no he cambiado de framework

Comment: Hola fredyfx, cuando cree la vista primero en mi controller cree el ActionResult Create y le hice click derecho y cree la vista, eso fue todo, p'ara crear la vista hice referencia a la capa de entidades para tener acceso al modelo y cree la vista con el modelo

Answer (score 1):

Te hace falta definir el `namespace` de donde se encuentra el modelo

```
@using Prueba.EntidadesDominio
@model Empleado
```

Comment: sigue dando el mismo error voy a eliminar el proyecto MVC y lo voy a volver a crear.

Comment: Se soluciono voiviendo a crear el proyecto Web.

Answer (score 1):

Me ha sucedido un par de veces y era que en la vista usaba `model.xxxx` y es `Model.xxx`.. Por ejemplo :

```
@foreach (Objeto objeto in Model.GetObjetos()) {
```

En todos los casos ¿Puedes publicar toda tu vista?

Y de paso también ¿Puedes compartir tu `web.config` porque también a veces está allí?

Comment: Hola @Mauricio. Bienvenido a [es.so] y gracias por el aporte. Te comento que para pedir más información, se recomienda hacerlo en los comentarios. Una vez que tengas la [reputación](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) podrás hacerlo. Lo que se busca es que las respuestas sean completas y tengan la información para resolver un problema sin consultar nada extra.

Comment: El gran Mauricio Sougarret llegó a StackOverflow en Español!! Bienvenido maestro!!

Comment: @fredyfx gracias por la bienvenida :)

Comment: De nada Mauricio! Gusto de saber que andas por estos lares de la red :D